# WPF binding with PlacementTarget and RelativeSource

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

Can you explain the following WPF code:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
```

I find it extremely confusing. What is placement target and what is relative source?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like a hack that is used for popup-elements such as `ContextMenus` and `Popup`-windows.
The problem with these elements is, that they are disconnected from the visual tree of your window. Therefore the `DataContext` is not available. The `PlacementTarget` is a link to an element of the visual-tree.
Mostly you will find a binding path like `PlacementTarget.Tag` where in the source element the `Tag` property has been set to the `DataContext` but in some situations, the element itself is also meaningful, such as in your example.

Assuming that the above code is used in a `ToolTip` or a `ContextMenu`, the `DataContext` will be set to the control that "owns" the element.

Look at the post from (Gishu +1) for an explanation of the mechanics.

Answer (score 11):

Every `FrameworkElement` has a `DataContext` that is an arbitrary object.  The default source for a data binding is that `DataContext`.  You can use `RelativeSource.Self` to change the source for a binding to the `FrameworkElement` itself instead of its `DataContext`.  So the `RelativeSource` part just moves you "up one level" from the `DataContext` of the `FrameworkElement` to the `FrameworkElement` itself.  Once you are at the `FrameworkElement` you can specify a path to any of its properties.  If the `FrameworkElement` is a `Popup`, it will have a `PlacementTarget` property that is the other `FrameworkElement` that the `Popup` is positioned relative to.

In short, if you have a `Popup` placed relative to a `TextBox` for example, that expression sets the `DataContext` of the `Popup` to the `TextBox` and as a result `{Binding Text}` somewhere in the body of the `Popup` would bind to the text of the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 7):

This is binding the DataContext of a thing (UI Control? need to see more of the code snippet ) to its own PlacementTarget property value.

[RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) is used to indicate the source object relative to the binding target. The path property indicates the name of the property on the source object.